# AttributeError: 'XGBRegressor' object has no attribute 'line_color'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost, yellowbrick

Find below the code I used to create the residuals_plot from yellowbrick package.
I ran the xgbregressor model, predicted the results and tried to create the residuals plot.
The plot came out properly, but followed with the below error. I didn't use the line_color
attribute at all anywhere in the code.

**AttributeError: 'XGBRegressor' object has no attribute 'line_color'** .

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this.

```
from yellowbrick.regressor import residuals_plot

print("\n                Residuals Plot")
residuals_plot(XGBR, MBxtrain, MBytrain, MBxtest,  MBytest)
```

[residuals_plot_from_yellowbrick_package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7p3B.png)